# igraph - adding text to community plot

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Using the code below I can generate a plot of the communities in the 'karate club' example provided by igraph (see first image).

```
library(igraph)
karate <- make_graph("Zachary")
wc <- cluster_walktrap(karate)
plot(wc, karate)
```

How can I add a text label 'near' each of the communities? For this example, say I want to call the 5 different communities "Community X" (X = 1:5). Ideally, the code would place the text labels on the 'outside' of the colored community polygons to create a clear graph (by placing the labels on the furthest xy coord from the center of the graph for each polygon). (See second image)

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374355/how-can-i-plot-igraph-community-with-defined-colors), but the only suggestion is to add the labels manually.

Any ideas on how to add the text labels with code? Is it possible to 'get' the xy coords of the community polygons and add the text labels that way? (Not sure if this should be a new question or a comment on the linked post's answer - let me know as I'm new to this).

Thanks a lot!

[image: igraph community example]

[image: igraph community example labeled]

EDIT: Based on the comment below, I identified the following code that seems to be drawing the polygons for each of the groups/communities:

```
params <- i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...))
#...
layout <- params("plot", "layout")
#....
for (g in seq_along(mark.groups)) {
v <- V(graph)[mark.groups[[g]]]
#...
igraph.polygon(layout[v, , drop = FALSE], vertex.size = vs, 
               expand.by = mark.expand[g]/200, shape = mark.shape[g], 
               col = mark.col[g], border = mark.border[g])
```

}

However, I can't find any information about the igraph.polygon function. I also don't know what to do with the params and 'layout[v, ,]'. Further, even if I could figure all this out, how would I change igraph's plotting function and add a text label??

Comment: At an R console prompt, enter `plot.igraph` and hit ENTER. No `()`. No params. You'll see the function source code. It's not pretty but it's straightforward to follow. You'll see how it computes the polygons and you should be able to replicate that. However, you then need to figure out optimal placing for the labels once you know the polygon points. That sounds like much more work than the annotation method described in the SO link you referred to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I looked into that for a while but I'm still stuck. I can't figure out how the actual plotting is being done; and even if I could figure that out I'm not sure how I would be able to add a text label within igraph's plotting function.

Comment: Then the post-plot annotations are the best forward path.