# r igraph - how does plot() read the layout matrix?

Tags: r, igraph

My question is related to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971179/igraph-adding-text-to-community-plot), which unfortunately has not been responded. I'm trying to automatically annotate text next to highlighted communities on a plot. An intermediate step is to understand how nodes are placed on a plot.

```
G <- make_graph('zachary')
l <- layout_with_fr(G)
l
```

A layout is a matrix with rows representing nodes and columns representing the x and y plot parameters.

```
           [,1]       [,2]
 [1,] 2.8510654 -2.2404898
 [2,] 2.7183497 -1.1815130
 [3,] 3.1429205  0.1117099
 [4,] 1.5585372 -1.0743325
 [5,] 2.2808632 -4.2035479
 [6,] 2.1698198 -5.0526766
 [7,] 1.4938068 -4.6975884
 [8,] 1.9710816 -1.4672218
 [9,] 3.5407035  0.5407852
[10,] 2.2222909  1.9079805
[11,] 3.0784642 -4.5828448
[12,] 4.4115351 -4.1057462
[13,] 0.6002378 -2.2432049
[14,] 2.5010525 -0.1563341
[15,] 4.8914673  4.1417759
[16,] 3.2053338  3.9212694
[17,] 1.1825200 -6.4099021
[18,] 3.7155897 -2.8354432
[19,] 3.8272351  4.2660906
[20,] 3.8636487 -0.5671906
[21,] 2.7302411  3.3998888
[22,] 1.6084374 -2.7407388
[23,] 4.3432855  3.8101278
[24,] 5.9392042  2.2364929
[25,] 6.9980077  0.2389222
[26,] 7.1608499  1.1360134
[27,] 6.0171481  4.0279067
[28,] 5.4996627  1.0367163
[29,] 4.4961257  0.9434659
[30,] 5.5987563  3.2314488
[31,] 2.9958404  1.2022317
[32,] 5.1188900  0.2919268
[33,] 4.1088296  2.5032294
[34,] 4.1686534  2.1339884
```

[image]

But the x, y coordinates of the plot go from -1 to 1, unlike the min-max coordinates in the layout matrix. So how is `plot(G, layout = l)` reading the layout matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The according to [the source](https://rdrr.io/cran/igraph/src/R/plot.R), the plot method for objects of class `igraph` simply rescales the matrix from `-1` to `1`.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(3)
l <- layout_with_fr(G)
        [,1]   [,2]
 [1,] -2.283  0.658
 [2,] -1.289 -0.108
 [3,]  0.146  1.012
 [4,] -1.523  1.601
#... with 30 more rows.
plot(G,layout = l)
```

[image]

```
maxs <- apply(l, 2, max)
mins <- apply(l, 2, min)
ll <- scale(l, center=(maxs+mins)/2, scale=(maxs-mins)/2)
ll
         [,1]    [,2]
 [1,] -0.2422 -0.1051
 [2,] -0.0704 -0.3821
 [3,]  0.1775  0.0228
 [4,] -0.1108  0.2357
#... with 30 more rows.
plot(G,layout = ll)
```

[image]

Note that the actual rescaling is performed with `igraph::norm_coords`:

```
igraph::norm_coords(l)
         [,1]    [,2]
 [1,] -0.2422 -0.1051
 [2,] -0.0704 -0.3821
 [3,]  0.1775  0.0228
 [4,] -0.1108  0.2357
#... with 30 more rows.
```