# r igraph - plot communies and selectively highlight some

Tags: r, plot, igraph

([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374355/how-can-i-plot-igraph-community-with-defined-colors) is a similar question to mine. I am using the example provided by @Slow loris in his excelent answer)

I am trying to plot `igraph` communities, but highlighting only selected communities. How do I do this?

```
library(igraph)

# Generate random graph and community structure
set.seed(23)
temp <- sample_gnm(15, 45)
wctemp <- walktrap.community(temp)

# Plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=rep(1,4))
layout <-layout.fruchterman.reingold(temp)
plot(wctemp, temp, layout=layout, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5,  edge.arrow.size=.2)
# Change colors of nodes, polygons, and polygon borders
new_cols <- c("white", "red", "black")[membership(wctemp)]
plot(wctemp, temp, col=new_cols, mark.border="black", mark.col=c("tan", "pink", "lightgray"), 
     layout=layout, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5, edge.arrow.size=.2)
```

[image]

In this example, I change can change the color of communities, but not select which ones to highlight. The expected solution highlights only selected communities, say the first and the third. Any takes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you mean that you do not want the polygon around group 2.  You can get this effect by setting the `mark.border` and the `mark.col` to NA.

```
plot(wctemp, temp, col=new_cols, mark.border=c("black", NA, "black"), 
     mark.col=c("tan", NA, "lightgray"), 
     layout=layout, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5, edge.arrow.size=.2)
```

[image: graph with selected groups highlighted]

**Addition:**

Based on the comments, I gather that you have a list of clusters to highlight and want to work from that list.  Just pick a point color for "not highlighted" (I used "darkgray") and make the polygon colors be NA except for the highlighted communities.

```
ToHighlight = c(1,3)

PCol = rep("darkgray", length(unique(wctemp$membership)))
PCol[ToHighlight] = rainbow(length(ToHighlight))
new_cols <- PCol[membership(wctemp)]

HCol = rep(NA, length(unique(wctemp$membership)))
HCol[ToHighlight] = rainbow(length(ToHighlight), alpha=0.15)

plot(wctemp, temp, col=new_cols, mark.border=HCol, mark.col=HCol, 
     layout=layout, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=5, edge.arrow.size=.2)
```

[image: Second version of highlighted communities]

Comment: Hi @G5W. This works for the example provided, but my actual network has many communities. Do you know a way of highlighting communities selected by name or index, as opposed to specifying the paramenters of all?

Comment: Made this more specific in answer.